# How does a message bridge relate to a queue in Weblogic?

Tags: bea

We have been discussing this at work and now I am even more confused than ever. As far as I understand it a message bridge is used to talk to a queue in a different domain. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Weblogic documentation:

> The WebLogic Messaging Bridge is a
>   forwarding mechanism that provides
>   interoperability between WebLogic JMS
>   implementations, and between JMS and
>   other messaging products. Use the
>   Messaging Bridge to integrate your
>   messaging applications between:
>
> - Any two implementations of WebLogic JMS, including those from separate
>     releases of WebLogic Server.
> - WebLogic JMS implementations that reside in separate WebLogic domains.
> - WebLogic JMS and a third-party JMS product (for example, MQSeries).

So transferring messages between a queue in one domain and a queue in another is an example of one possible use of a message bridge. The source and destination for your bridge can be queues, topics, or distributed destinations.